# Adding Images stored in JSON Array in a ListView - ReactNative

Tags: javascript, ios, json, listview, react-native

I'm having trouble displaying images stored in a JSON array in a ReactNative ListView. Let's say this is my data:

```
var data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    photo: '../images/test.png',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    photo: '../images/test.png',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    photo: '../images/test.png',
  },
]
```

Then, in my class, first I require the data (assume it's being exported correctly):

```
var data = require("../data").data
```

Then for each element in the datasource, I loop through the JSON array, and try to display the Image:

```
<Image source={{uri:item.photo}} style={styles.photo}></Image>
```

However, nothing displays on screen. I know the data is being pulled through correctly because other text fields (not shown above) display properly, for example:

```
<Text style = {styles.name}>{item.id}</Text>
```

This displays properly. Also if I try to require the image directly in the source, i.e.

```
<Image source={require('../images/test.png')} style={styles.photo}></Image>
```

It works fine. Does anyone know why the Image source isn't pulling when referenced as a variable?

Comment: Yes, you cannot do that. `source:{{uri: blablabla}}` is for fetching network images. For local image you need to require them. And you cannot give the `require` a dynamic path. The path must be static.

Comment: But I am giving require a static path, right? For example `data[0].photo` would be the static path that the Image source needs to refer to?

Comment: That would be , but you are putting that path dynamically to require, which I think is not permitted. One way would be, You can put the require in your database.

Comment: @AakashSigdel is right. For some solutions see http://stackoverflow.com/q/36911856/1783214

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in this way:

```js
var data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    photo: require('../images/test.png'),
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    photo: require('../images/test.png'),
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    photo: require('../images/test.png'),
  },
]
```